# ansible start process if not running using ps

Tags: linux, centos, ansible

i am using ansible to start the namenode process if incase its not running, I am using `jps` to check for the process and check the status using `service_namenode_status` and start the process using `service_namenode_start` any idea how to use this properly...?

```
  - name: Check if Namenode is running
    shell: jps | grep " NameNode" | grep -v grep
    ignore_errors: yes
    changed_when: false
    register: service_namenode_status

  - name: Report status of Namenode
    fail:
      msg: |
        Service NameNode is not running.
        Return code from `jps | grep " NameNode" | grep -v grep`:
        {{ service_namenode_status.rc }}
    when: service_namenode_status.rc != 0
    register: service_namenode_start

  - name: Start Namenode
    command: su - hdfs -c "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start namenode"
    tags: namenode
    when: service_namenode_status.rc != 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
TASK [namenode : Check if Namenode is running] *********************************
fatal: [server1.hdp.vagrant.data.uc]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "jps | grep \" NameNode\" | grep -v grep", "delta": "0:00:00.192755", "end": "2016-11-09 10:59:10.360552", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-11-09 10:59:10.167797", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
...ignoring

TASK [namenode : Report status of Namenode] ************************************
fatal: [server1.hdp.vagrant.data.uc]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Service NameNode is not running.\nReturn code from `jps | grep \" NameNode\" | grep -v grep`:\n1  \n"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

RUNNING HANDLER [metastore : restart postgresql] *******************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/Users/krisdigitx/myLab/hdp/provisioning/site.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
server1.hdp.vagrant.data.uc : ok=86   changed=32   unreachable=0    failed=1

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- name: Check if Namenode is running
  tags: namenode
  shell: jps | grep " NameNode" | grep -v grep
  ignore_errors: yes
  changed_when: false
  register: service_namenode_status

- name: Start Namenode
  tags: namenode
  command: su - hdfs -c "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR start namenode"
  when: service_namenode_status.rc == 1
```

My changes were:

1. I added the "tags: namenode" line to the 1st part; you'll need to collect the register value if you are filtering on this tag
2. I removed your 2nd part and went straight to the 3rd.

A similar config is working for me for a similar problem.

Comment: I greped with the following: `if [[ $(pgrep -f NameNode | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]; then return 1; else return 0; fi`. Also I think there is a space too much at grep " Namenode".